# how to create PDF in grayscale mode or TikZ figure only?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, color, output

how to create PDF in grayscale mode?
convert PDF color in PDF grayscale.
I need the PDF in grayscale color.
Or in TikZ figure only.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For TikZ figures, you can use the `xcolor` command `\selectcolormodel{gray}` before or at the start of your `tikzpicture`. This won't turn images that you import with `\includegraphics` to grayscale, though.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[radius=0.5cm]
\selectcolormodel{gray}
\fill [red] (0,0) circle;
\fill [green] (1,0) circle;
\fill [blue] (2,0) circle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[radius=0.5cm]
\fill [red] (0,0) circle;
\fill [green] (1,0) circle;
\fill [blue] (2,0) circle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

In ConTeXt `\setupcolors[state=stop]` should do that.