# Monochrome in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to create PDF in grayscale mode or TikZ figure only?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25703/how-to-create-pdf-in-grayscale-mode-or-tikz-figure-only)

How to convert tikz figure in monochrome?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[red] circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But i need the below result:

[image]

Comment: Didn't you ask exactly that question before? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25703/how-to-create-pdf-in-grayscale-mode-or-tikz-figure-only

Answer (score 6):

If the monochrome model must be applied to all the document, you can pass the `monochrome` option to `xcolor`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{monochrome}{xcolor}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[red] circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For some particular `tikzfigure` environment(s) you can use the approach mentioned by **Jake** in his answer to [how to create PDF in grayscale mode or TikZ figure only?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25703/3954).

Comment: However this will change the colour mode for the entire document, not only the tikz figure. This is fine if the figure is in a standalone file, but as part of a bigger document, you may not want to do that. The answer provided by @jake in the question he linked is probably more appropriate.

Comment: @ArTourter you're right. I've added some comment about this to my answer. Thank you!