# Change TikZ nodes color to grayscale

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

Say you have some code like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
% \PassOptionsToPackage{monochrome}{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% \selectcolormodel{gray}
 \node[fill=red] at (0,1) {text};
 \node[fill=green] at (0,0.5) {text};
 \node[fill=blue] at (0,0){text};
 \node[fill=yellow] at (1,1) {text};
 \node[fill=violet] at (1,0.5) {text};
 \node[fill=orange] at (1,0) {text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]
And you want to turn the resulting picture in grayscale colors. Is there a way to do this in LaTeX without using external tools (convert, imagemagick, etc.) and, of course, without having to manually change all the color values?

I already tried with the methods from [how to create PDF in grayscale mode or TikZ figure only?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25703/how-to-create-pdf-in-grayscale-mode-or-tikz-figure-only) and [Monochrome in Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63849/monochrome-in-tikz) (see the commented code) but they both do not seem to work when the color is specified as a node option.

It would be also nice to know why the `\selectcolormodel{gray}` method does not work in this context.

Comment: `\PassOptionsToPackage{gray}{xcolor}` works when put *before* loading TikZ.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel You should make an answer out of it!

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Gosh! I tried with `monochrome` in every possible position and didn't think about `gray`! I'll accept your answer if you'll make one, but maybe this may now be considered a duplicate?

Comment: Interestingly, while `\node[fill=<color>]` won’t work, `\node[<color>, draw=none, fill, text=black]` does. (`<color>` is internally passed to TikZ key `color`). I guess TikZ uses on some point his own color definition by-passing `xcolor`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you mean with *without having to manually change all the color values?*.

If you only want to avoid to change your picture, then the following solution may be a solution:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{red}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{green}{gray}{0.8}
\definecolor{blue}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{yellow}{gray}{0.6}
\definecolor{violet}{gray}{0.5}
\definecolor{orange}{gray}{0.4}


\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[fill=red] at (0,1) {text};
 \node[fill=green] at (0,0.5) {text};
 \node[fill=blue] at (0,0){text};
 \node[fill=yellow] at (1,1) {text};
 \node[fill=violet] at (1,0.5) {text};
 \node[fill=orange] at (1,0) {text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You redefine all colors, but only once per document. Your tikzpicture is unchanged.

You also may put the redefinitions to a style 'grey_colors.sty' and reuse it for differnt documents.

---

Qrrbrbirlbel gave a better solution with `\PassOptionsToPackage{gray}{xcolor}` when put before loading TikZ.

You may combine the two solutions. The redefinition of the colors gives you a better control on which grey tone a color should get.

Example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\PassOptionsToPackage{gray}{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

gray-option:
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[fill=red] at (0,1) {text};
 \node[fill=green] at (0,0.5) {text};
 \node[fill=blue] at (0,0){text};
 \node[fill=yellow] at (1,1) {text};
 \node[fill=violet] at (1,0.5) {text};
 \node[fill=orange] at (1,0) {text};
\end{tikzpicture}

Color redefinition:
\definecolor{red}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{green}{gray}{0.8}
\definecolor{blue}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{yellow}{gray}{0.6}
\definecolor{violet}{gray}{0.5}
\definecolor{orange}{gray}{0.4}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[fill=red] at (0,1) {text};
 \node[fill=green] at (0,0.5) {text};
 \node[fill=blue] at (0,0){text};
 \node[fill=yellow] at (1,1) {text};
 \node[fill=violet] at (1,0.5) {text};
 \node[fill=orange] at (1,0) {text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This may be a solution if you have only few colors and not very similar. The actual document has lots of not so different colors (that's why I said I would not want to change them manually) so an automated approach is preferred.

Comment: I think I would combine the two answers. `\PassOptionsToPackage{gray}{xcolor}` to set all colors to gray and the specific color redefinition for some selected colors, if a color does not look like I want (e.g. if two colors look very similar when they get a gray value).